# How to add a chronometer to a dialog

Tags: android, kotlin

So I wanted to add a chronometer in my app to display how long the app is open.
I want the chronometer to start when the app is opened. So that means it has to be started in MainActivity. But I don't want to display it in the MainActivity. The chronometer will be displayed in a dialog. How do I pass the chronometer to this dialog and also show the time running. I tried this just to test the chronometer:

```
val upTimeCounter = infoView.findViewById<Chronometer>(R.id.upTime)
upTimeCounter.start()
```

Whats the best way to pass the chronometer to a dialog but still keep the time instead of stopping it and starting at 0 when the dialog is opened?